# Sanitizing Apostrophes with PHP

Tags: mysql, php, str-replace, apostrophe

I am having trouble with apostrophes causing errors in a grading system I have setup. When a customer submits a paper that contains apostrophes, I am replacing all apostrophes with PHP like so:

```
//Now remove Apostrophes
$essay = str_replace("'","", $essay) ;
```

The problem is though this does not work for all types of different apostrophes. An example:

This apostrophe **’** is different than this apostrophe **'**. I am guessing the solution is to update the `$essay` variable to a standard apostrophe type and then use `str_replace` to remove all apostrophes.

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is? Why do you think apostrophes have something to do with it? Are you suffering from an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: You should fix the errors instead of limiting / changing the input.

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle The error it is causing is that when I am trying to remove all Apostrophes is that it will remove the "'" type but not the "’" type or all of the other types. How do I remove all types of apostrophes?

Comment: I would assume you are actually having a more troublesome character encoding problem. Is everything you are using in UTF8?

Comment: Since this is tagged with mysql I'm assuming you're building your queries like `$q = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE var = '$var'";`. Aside from the security implications there is the apostrophe problem. If you use parameterized queries with PDO or mySQLi you will not have to remove or replace apostrophes, as well as having increased security against injection.

Comment: I want to know what the error is, not how you think you are going to solve it.

Comment: Why are apostrophes causing you trouble?

Comment: The point is: don't reinvent variable sanitizing functions - someone else has already done it better.

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle I responded to your first comment with the error. When I an trying to store this in a database, I want all apostrophes removed. But there seems to be so many different types. How do I convert all apostrophes into 1 style and then remove them from the `$essay` variable?

Comment: @Ivo Please ready my last comment to PatrickJamesMcDougle

Comment: Why do you want the apostrophes gone? You still haven't answered that.

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle Because I do not want them stored in the database at all. I know you probably do not agree with that, but it goes along with what I am trying to accomplish. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: When you say apostrophe, you also mean right curly quotes and all the others listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs#Quotation_marks_in_Unicode)?

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle Yes, that is correct. Is there a way to sanitize all of these?

Comment: Storing apostrophes (or any other special character) in a MySQL table is perfectly possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't agree with your perilous vendetta against proper typography, I can tell you that you will need a `str_replace()` for each of the different kinds of apostrophe-esque characters that there are. Just do a bunch of `str_replace()` s with each kind of apostrophes you want removed.

I still think you are trying to solve a problem by avoiding it rather than solving it. Apostrophes are perfectly ok to put into a mysql database, it might just need to have a different character set or collation.

Comment: @three3 please read my answer on database sanatization. Trying to do it manually will probably just land you in more trouble down the road!

Comment: @Ivo they aren't doing sanitation, they have some vendetta against apostrophes. Why else would it matter that they want curly quotes gone too?

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle I'm not going to give him the benefit of the doubt here. He just hasn't learned about prepared statements (or even escaped values)

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about trying to sanatize data (i.e - at the moment you're trying to remove apostrophes...) for database insertion yourself. This is a solved problem.

The best solution is to use the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) database connector to insert data with prepared queries.

There is no need to do validation / sanatizing  for insertion at all - your database will store all the data correctly when you let it.

If you are still using `mysql_*` functions, **please don't**. They are very old, and soon to be deprecated, and allow for many, many programming mistakes and exploits in an application when not used with extreme care.

[Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/) is a decent tutorial on how to use PDO. Remember, if you use it correctly with prepared statements, you won't need to worry about sanatizing! You won't need to worry about apostrophes of any kind! The PDO connector will do it for you!

Answer (score 0):

What are you sanitizing it for?

Submission into a database?  [real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Returning it to the URL for a get request?  [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

The specific reason why you're sanitizing it helps us to figure out the best way to do it!

Comment: When I an trying to store this in a database, I want all apostrophes removed. But there seems to be so many different types of apostrophes. How do I convert all apostrophes into 1 style and then remove them from the $essay variable?

Comment: @WolfmanJoe Because I do not want them stored in the database at all. I know you probably do not agree with that, but it goes along with what I am trying to accomplish. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: @Three3 Tell us more about **why** you want to solve the problem by not storing the apostrophes.  If you don't share more information with us, we think you have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) or haven't paid attention to [Keep an Open Mind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  We can't help without context as to exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  'Get rid of apostrophes' is so vague.

Answer (score 0):

Try [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) if you're trying to prevent XSS attacks.

```
$essay=filter_var($essay, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

If you're trying to protect against sql injection, look up parameterized queries.